# R stepAIC - Does this function use the exact dataset as the model was built?

Tags: r

Today while utilizing the stepAIC function to narrow down a list of variables, I had a thought about how the function was exactly working. Consider this code:

```
for (i in 1:5) {

model <- lm(train_y ~ ., data = train[fold != i,])
model <- stepAIC(model)

}
```

In this example, each iteration is subsetting the training dataset based on the fold variable. When the stepAIC executes, will it 'honor' the row filtering that was originally applied, or will it use the entire 'train' dataset.

I see the documentation says this: "The model fitting must apply the models to the same dataset." , but I dont know if it is just using the same dataset name, or it uses the same filtering as well.

I know there are lots of discussions about the correct way to select features via lasso, stepwise, etc. , so im just interested here is how the the function is working. I am aware there are likely better ways to select variables.

Thanks

Comment: It uses the data passed to the original model. In your example that is the subset.

Comment: Thats what I was hoping, though I wasnt 100% sure if this was actually the case or not. Thanks.

Comment: You deleted your "looping" query today (9 Feb 2018). I wanted to let you know that, apart from eliminating the `print(paste0...` line, you can gain a huge improvement by changing `rand_months` to `rand_months<-1:12` and your `buyers_months <- sample_n...` line to `sample(rand_months)`. I was shocked how much time this saved. Best, Edw.C.

Comment: @EdwardCarney I actually came to these same two conclusions not long ago haha. I too was quite amazed, it went from 2 hours to 11 seconds after I found these two changes.